# Do you have to add unimplemented methods?

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

I am trying to add a listener to a `JFrame` closing operation:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowListener() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

The thing is that Eclipse keeps telling me I have to "add unimplemented methods", which I assume it gets from the `WindowListener`. I am confused, though, as to why you need to implement all these other methods as well, if you only need to override one? And if I do add all those other methods, but don't put any content in them e.g.

```
@Override
public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {}
```

will the default behaviour for this method get lost? Or will it only get overriden if I write something inside the method?

Comment: Since you add a windowslistener it will still use the default behavior from the other `WindowListener` that might have been added previously. It just says that for this specific `WindowListener` that you are adding the "default behavior" for the other methods is to do nothing.

Comment: You need to understand the topic "interface in java", http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you implement an interface you must implement all methods. That also applies for anonymous classes.

Use [`WindowAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html) instead of implementing `WindowListener`

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

`WindowAdapter` is a class that implements `WindowListener` with empty methods and let you override only the ones you need.

**PS:** There are also other adapters for other events in swing. E.g. [`MouseAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html), [`KeyAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to implement all methods.

This is how [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) work: they define a contract that implementors must follow. If that contract consists of 5 methods then you have to implement all 5 of them.

When there is a consequent number of methods, the Adapter design-pattern is usually put in place: an abstract class that provides default implementation that do nothing is created.

For the [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) interface, this is [`WindowAdapter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowAdapter.html). So, instead of implementing `WindowListener` (and all of its methods), you can just extend `WindowAdapter` and override only the methods you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default behaviour, that's why you need to provide an implementation (the expected behaviour).

As soon as you have a concrete class extend either an abstract class, or implement an interface, it MUST provide an implementation for all abstract methods.

This can be done through an (other) super class, or in the class itself, but yes, it is mandatory.

You override it, as soon as you add the method, but since there is no previous implementation, no 'default behaviour' for these methods that can be lost.